# how to using swingworker to a jprogressbar <update>

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a swingworker that will be representing a jProgressbar. This is the code

```
private Swingworker timeOfProccess;

class Swingworker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

        jProgressBar1.setStringPainted(true);
        int progress = 0;
        setProgress(0);

        while (progress <= 100) {
            jProgressBar1.setValue(progress);
            Thread.sleep(5);
            progress++;
        }
        mainProccess();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        jProgressBar1.setValue(100);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Proses Selesai");
        jProgressBar1.setValue(0);
        jProgressBar1.setStringPainted(false);
    }

}

private void btnExecuteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    timeOfProccess = new Swingworker();
    timeOfProccess.execute();}
```

I dont know, why the progressbar running is uncontrolled. it is so fast to 100% even the process still working. But void done is success to pop-up  the JoptionPane after main process end. where is I am lost in my code. thanks..

Comment: Don't update the GUI from the background thread; use `setProgress()`, as shown in this [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4637215/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Visit [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) where You will find good examples on progress bar along with detail description.

Don't use `Thread.sleep()` that sometime hangs the whole swing application instead try with [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) that is most suitable for swing application.

Read more [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

sample code:

```
// delay for 1500 mill-seconds
Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1500, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // call for your next task
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true); // you can turn off the repetition
timer.start();
```

---

> How to get the progressbar showing the number 1 - 100 %.

Use [JProgressBar#setStringPainted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setStringPainted%28boolean%29) method to show the percent done status.

[image]